# load jquery after the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to load jquery after the page is fully loaded. 
well there are lots of questions and answers about it in here, but all describe how to run a script that needs jquery after either page or jquery fully loaded. 
What I'm looking for is to load the page and then call jquery and after the jquery is loaded call the functions. something like:

```
document.onload=function(){
   var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
  //Here I need an event to know that jquery is 
  //loaded to run stuff that needs jquery
}
```

Comment: Can I know why you need this?

Comment: well google analytics keep saying that the script slows down my page load and suggests loading it after page loads

Comment: Maybe you could put the Javascript code in a separate file and then include that script at the bottom of the body

Comment: for me this explains verry nicely when to load the js and why.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999638/when-has-a-function-to-be-in-document-ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked this question more than 6 years ago, and any answers I got had some flaws. Later I myself worked out a solution that I have been using for years since then. Now that I came across my own question again and I saw that it has many views, I'd like to share it because I think it may help others.

This problem mainly occurs on Master-Detail type of pages (can be old .master and .aspx pages) or (layout and views in asp.net) or any similar situation maybe on other web development languages, however always there is a master-detail pattern involved.

For the solution, I just add an array at the beginning of my page:

```
<script>var after = [];</script>
```

any function that requires jQuery or any other script that would run after this section, instead of running it, I just push it to this array:

```
after.push(function(){
     // code that requires scripts that will load later,
     //might be for example a jQuery selector or ...
});
```

and then at the very end of the page, right before closing the body tag (of course scripts are loaded by now) I run all the functions inside the (here named) `after` array:

```
<script>for(var i=0;i<after.length;i++)after[i]();</script>
</body>
```

I find this way very easy, simple and flawless.

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
// When the document is ready
// Do something  
});
```

Comment: great! thanks. I have always been wondering what this .ready is :)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    // Your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For your problem, the solution might be to attach CDN hosted by google with certain library:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Also, you can add this at the bottom of page (just before `</body>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script)
})();
</script>
```

However, this is risky in my opinion. You have an asynchronous call for jquery, thus your jquery has to wait until it loads (ie. `$(document).ready` won't work in this case). So my answer would be: use a CDN like google suggests; put your javascript on the bottom just before `</body>`; and, ignore flags from profilers.

Comment: after I call it, where to put scripts that needs jquery to run?

Comment: Edit for clarity. Sorry for not noting question in a comment earlier. If you use my snippet, probably the only option you have is to put your code below. So it will be something like: <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { ... my code ... })(); </script> just underneath of snippet. Code will be evaluated sequentially, so you can be sure that you going to have jQuery loaded (I believe - I always used google's CDN in fact).

Comment: You can use `window.onload()` to wait until jquery is loaded if you just put your resources in using the usual method.

Answer (score 4):

It is advised to load your scripts at the bottom of your `<body>` block to speed up the page load, like this:

```
<body>
<!-- your content -->
<!-- your scripts -->
<script src=".."></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) function. It runs a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
window.onload=function(){
      // Run code
    };
```

Or another way is : **Include scripts at the bottom of your page**.

Comment: **$( window )** means that jquery is loaded in the document. but there is no jquery. we want to create it and the run the jquery codes

Comment: I am using [window.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) function of javascript here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using your function and using a timeout waiting until the jQuery object is loaded

Code:

```
document.onload=function(){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    waitForjQuery();
}

function waitForjQuery() {
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
        // do some stuff
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () { waitForjQuery(); }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is more likely what i'm looking for, isn't there anyway to fire an event when the loading jquery is done and not checking it with timeouts?

Comment: I'm using this method, I can't find any alternative at the moment

Comment: This solution might be an overkill you can kill performance of a browser to get a better performance on google analytics. Isn't it a lack of common sense? CDNs with common libraries + one minified custom javascript should be enough, imho.

Comment: Depends on bandwidth, computer/browser speed and so on. It is to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you load jQuery in the `<head>` section of your page. While this is not harmful, it slows down page load. Try using this pattern to speed up initial loading time of the DOM-Tree:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('body').append('<p>I can happily use jQuery</p>');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just add your scripts at the end of your `<body>`tag.

There are some scripts that need to be in the head due to practical reasons, the most prominent library being **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)**

Comment: As you always need to wait for the dom-ready event anyway (that's why you do `$(document).ready(...)`), you will notice no difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you can load jQuery from your own server, then you can append this to your jQuery file:

`jQuery(document).trigger('jquery.loaded');`

then you can bind to that triggered event.

Answer (score 0):

Include your scripts at the **bottom** of the page before closing **body** tag.

More info [HERE](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid loading jquery until your content has been loaded, the best way is to simply put the reference to it in the bottom of your page, like many other answers have said.

### General tips on Jquery usage:

1. **Use a CDN.** This way, your site can use the cached version a user likely has on their computer. The `//` at the beginning allows it to be called (and use the same resource) whether it's http or https. Example:

   `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Using a CDN has a couple of big benefits: it makes it more likely that users have it cached from another site, so there will be no download (and no render-blocking). Further, CDNs use the closest, fastest connection available, meaning that if they do need to load it, it will probably be faster than connecting to your server. [More info from Google.](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

2. **Put scripts at the bottom.** Move as much of your js to the bottom of the page as possible. I use php to include a file with all my JS resources below the footer.
3. If you're using a template system, you may need to have javascript spread throughout the html output. If you're using jquery in scripts that get called as the page renders, this will cause errors. To **have your scripts wait until jquery is loaded**, put them into

   `window.onload() = function () { //... your js that isn't called by user interaction ... }`

This will prevent errors but still run before user interaction and without timers.

Of course, if jquery is cached, it won't matter too much where you put it, except to page speed tools that will tell you you're blocking rendering.