# jQuery sort in document.ready

Tags: jquery

How can I call this sort function in `document.ready`?

```
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {

      var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('data-sort'));
      var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('data-sort'));
      return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
   })
```

I tried like this, but it does not work

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('div').sort(function (a, b) {

        var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-sort'));
        var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-sort'));
        return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;

    })
    });
```

Comment: You are having ternary operator wrongly use...

Comment: possible duplicate of [load jquery after the page is fully loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026345/load-jquery-after-the-page-is-fully-loaded)

Comment: `sort` won't change the DOM, just the jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Stick it inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ...  });`

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').sort(function (a, b) {

      var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('data-sort'));
      var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('data-sort'));
      return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    // your document is ready
    sortyourcoolstuff();
    });
```

and, as C-Link Nepal stated, usage of ternary operator is wrong.

```
return (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;
```

this will return 1 if `b>a`, `else` 0. change it according to your own context.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').sort(function (a, b) {

      var contentA = a.getAttribute('data-sort'));
      var contentB = b.getAttribute('data-sort'));
      if(contentA > contentB ) {
        return 1;
       }
      if(contentA < contentB ) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean extending a Jquery prototype, you need to add before your code the following:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
     sort: function(a, b){
          var contentA =parseInt( $(a).attr('data-sort'));
          var contentB =parseInt( $(b).attr('data-sort'));
          return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;         
   }
});
```