# jquery real time text update and display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a replica of text in real time from a `<input>` to another `<h5>`. Following code, I already tried with jquery 3.1 but not works. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />

<h5 id="show"><h5/>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
  $('#show').text($(this).val());
});
```

```js
$('#name').keyup(function() {
  $('#show').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />

<h5 id="show">
  <h5/>
```

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: Check the snippet in the question. Works fine

Comment: Have you added the `keyup` listener once document is ready?

Comment: Already working code

Comment: Hi! Where do you have this function? If the jQuery loads before the elements are ready that might be the issue. 
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026345/load-jquery-after-the-page-is-fully-loaded/19027329#19027329

Comment: @PM. is correct. Thanks for advice. this works now. I missed doc ready

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){  // Your code here...  });` Put all your codes in jquery main function

Answer (score -3):

it's simple use class="show" instead of id="show"

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<h5 class="show"></h5>
<h5 class="show"></h5>
<h5 class="show"></h5>
```

Then here is js code

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
  $('.show').html('').append($(this).val());
});
```

simple :)